# How to enable zoom in and zoom out on a contentpage in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I enable zoom on a contentpage in xamarin forms? Is it possible to enable it on the entire contentpage? Or is it only possible to zoom in on images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pinch gesture inside a `ContentPage`, here is the official page:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pinch/

and for the entire project sample:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithGestures/PinchGesture

Here is an example of what you can achieve:

[Xamarin.Forms Pinch Example](https://media.giphy.com/media/rnrhBbYSwWqUo/giphy.gif)

Comment: Zoom option not working when the page content along with an image to zoom, is inside scrollview. Is there anything to do in zoom container class?

Answer (score 2):

Try this Class , this solution do not scroll when you zoom .
Source found here:
[Source Code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithGestures/PinchGesture)

```
    public class PinchToZoomContainer : ContentView {
    double currentScale = 1;
    double startScale = 1;
    double xOffset = 0;
    double yOffset = 0;

    public PinchToZoomContainer ()
    {
        var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer ();
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add (pinchGesture);
    }

    void OnPinchUpdated (object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started) {
            // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
            // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
            startScale = Content.Scale;
            Content.AnchorX = 0;
            Content.AnchorY = 0;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running) {
            // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
            currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
            currentScale = Math.Max (1, currentScale);

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the X pixel coordinate.
            double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
            double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
            double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
            double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
            double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
            double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
            double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
            double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

            // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
            double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
            double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

            // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
            Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp (-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
            Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp (-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

            // Apply scale factor
            Content.Scale = currentScale;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed) {
            // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
            xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
            yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
        }
    }
}
```

Helper DoubleExtensions

```
    public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    public static double Clamp (this double self, double min, double max)
    {
        return Math.Min (max, Math.Max (self, min));
    }
}
```

Comment: Zoom option not working when the page content along with an image to zoom, is inside scrollview. Is there anything to do in zoom container class?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Scale Api on the Content page. This seemed to work for me on a small test app.

```
public App ()
{
    // The root page of your application
    var scaleUp = new Button {
        Text = "Scale Up"
    };
    scaleUp.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
        this.MainPage.Scale += 1;
    };

    var scaleDown = new Button {
        Text = "Scale Down"
    };
    scaleDown.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        this.MainPage.Scale -= 1;
    };

    MainPage = new ContentPage {
        Content = new StackLayout {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
                scaleUp,
                scaleDown

            }
        }
    };
}
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: If you put the buttons on the bottom of the page, will they move out of the view as you zoom in?

Comment: @WilliamCorncobDecker I added images to show what it does.

Comment: I'm just concerned that in practice this is not a feasible option. Most people will not want buttons in the middle of their layouts, they would want them on the top or bottom of the screen. In those cases the buttons would quickly move out of the visible area.

Comment: @WilliamCorncobDecker This was just a proof of concept. I'm sure you could create gestures so that you can zoom in and out view pinch or even just move all your content into a zoomable layout and have your buttons live outside so they are not affected.

Comment: Ok. So there isn't really a solution out there right now that enables zooming (with your hands) for xamarin forms?

Comment: @medvedo You can add a pinch gesture like in this example https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pinch/ but instead of the content being the image. The content would be the actual page.

Comment: Zoom option not working when the page content along with an image to zoom, is inside scrollview. Is there anything to do in zoom container class?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use this in conjunction with other controls that take the Pan/scroll gesture seems to fail.  ScrollView and ListView for example grab the Pinch gesture even though they themselves don't Pinch but they do scroll/pan.  So it seems like Pinch inherits/uses that gesture so it is grabbed by the wrapped control.  This seems to make Pinch a very niche feature that can only work on very static views of Label and Image for example, but nothing more complex.

Answer (score -1):

You can use gestures.
Sample here : http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/